# Do different decompositions of Dehn twists induce the same cobordisms between mapping tori?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, mapping-class-groups, 4-manifolds

Suppose $Y=T^2\times I/f$ is a mapping torus, where $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $T^2$. Suppose $c$ is a curve on $T^2\times \{1\}$ with surface framing and suppose $D_c$ is the positive Dehn twist along $c$. Then $-1$ surgery on $c$ gives $Y'=T^2\times I/f\circ D_c$. Also, by attaching 4d 2-handle, we have a cobordism $W_c$ from $Y$ to $Y'$ associated to $-1$ surgery on $c$.

Suppose $h$ is another diffeomorphism of $T^2$ that can be decomposed along positive Dehn twists. Is there a well-defined cobordism $W_h$ from $Y$ to $Y''=T^2\times I/f\circ h$, i.e., is it independent of the decompositiom of Dehn twists?

Comment: Technically it's not a Dehn twist you are decomposing here, it's the monodromy of the bundle, i.e. the mapping you use to define your mapping torus.   Without some further context I suppose the answer is clearly no.  If you don't put any constraints on your cobordism, you could have pretty  much anything.   This is like asking if there is a well-defined null-cobordism of a circle.  There is a well-defined minimal-genus cobordism, but if you don't put any constraints on the cobordism, you can get anything.